# How to copy every 4th file in a folder

Tags: bash, files, cp

I have a lot of files in a folder, named like `00802_Bla_Aquarium_XXXXX.jpg`. Now I need to copy every **4th** file to a subfolder, saying in `selected/`.

```
00802_Bla_Aquarium_00020.jpg <= this one
00802_Bla_Aquarium_00021.jpg
00802_Bla_Aquarium_00022.jpg
00802_Bla_Aquarium_00023.jpg
00802_Bla_Aquarium_00024.jpg <= this one
00802_Bla_Aquarium_00025.jpg
00802_Bla_Aquarium_00026.jpg
00802_Bla_Aquarium_00027.jpg
00802_Bla_Aquarium_00028.jpg <= this one
00802_Bla_Aquarium_00029.jpg
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You might be able to do like the solutions to http://superuser.com/q/396536/87552 on some output of `ls`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4553751/789593 which asks about every second line.

Comment: If they're numbered and you know the last number, you might consider a variation of `for n in $(seq -w 20 4 200); do cp "00802_..._00${n}" ...; done`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With zsh, you could do:

```
n=0; cp 00802_Bla_Aquarium_?????.jpg(^e:'((n++%4))':) /some/place
```

POSIXly, same idea, just a bit more verbose:

```
# put the file list in the positional parameters ($1, $2...).
# the files are sorted in alphanumeric order by the shell globbing
set -- 00802_Bla_Aquarium_?????.jpg

n=0
# loop through the files, increasing a counter at each iteration.
for i do
  # every 4th iteration, append the current file to the end of the list
  [ "$(($n % 4))" -eq 0 ] && set -- "$@" "$i"

  # and pop the current file from the head of the list
  shift
  n=$(($n + 1))
done

# now "$@" contains the files that have been appended.
cp -- "$@" /some/place
```

Since those filenames don't contain any blank or wildcard characters, you could also do:

```
cp $(printf '%s\n' 00802_Bla_Aquarium_?????.jpg | awk 'NR%4 == 1') /some/place
```

Comment: Can you please put comment also in posix code

Comment: @ChrisDown, `for i do` is standard and actually more portable than `for i; do` and is the canonical way to loop over the positional parameters.

Answer (score 8):

In bash, a funny possibility, that will work rather well here:

```
cp 00802_Bla_Aquarium_*{00..99..4}.jpg selected
```

That's definitely the shortest and most efficient answer: no subshell, no loop, no pipe, no `awk`ward external process; just one fork to `cp` (that you can't avoid anyway) and one bash brace expansion and glob (that you can get rid of altogether since you know how many files you have).

Comment: … and 2 assumptions: files are numbered continuously and the first one is divisible with 4.

Comment: @manatwork no problem if first one is not divisible by 4: e.g., `cp 00802_Bla_Aquarium_*{03..99..4}.jpg selected` if you want `3 mod 4`. (I'm using the wonderful fact that 100 is divisible by 4). Now, about continuously numbered files, all the other answers assume the same.

Comment: Which other answers assume continuous numbering? I found only [Ulrich Schwarz's comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59089/how-to-copy-every-4th-file-in-a-folder/59131#comment81531_59089) and no such answer.

Answer (score 7):

Simply with bash, you can do:

```
n=0
for file in ./*.jpg; do
   test $n -eq 0 && cp "$file" selected/
   n=$((n+1))
   n=$((n%4))
done
```

The pattern `./*.jpg` will be replaced by an alphabetically  sorted  list of file names as stated by the bash man, so it should fit your purpose.

Comment: In bash, your three line inside the `for` loop can be replaced with just this line: `(((++n)%4)) || cp "$file" selected/`. `;-)`. The problem though is that you're forking on a `cp` for _each_ file which is not really efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `ruby` installed you can use the following one-liner. Note that it assumes that the directory selected exists.

```ruby
ruby -rfileutils -e 'files = Dir.glob("*.jpg").each_slice(4) { |file| FileUtils.cp(file.first, "selected/" + file.first) }'
```

It takes a list of all files with the extension .jpg in the current directory and slices it into lists of four elements and copies the first element from each such list to the directory selected in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you will not have newlines in your file names, you could use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" | sort | while IFS= read -r file; do
  cp "$file" selected/
  IFS= read -r; IFS= read -r; IFS= read -r
done
```

Comment: @Gilles: thanks for the edit.  I removed the file variable in the 3 read though, as I want to point out that they are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GUI file manager and resize the border of the window until every 5 files occupy a row, and then use mouse to select the first column...

Answer (score 0):

This solution relies on text utils, but should work in less advanced shells too:

```
cp `ls * | awk 'NR % 4 == 0'` selected
```

Note that it may break if the number of files is too big. In that case I would go with slower xargs way:

```
ls * | awk 'NR % 4 == 0' | xargs -i cp {} selected
```

Comment: be careful with using `ls` to enumerate files, as it can cause all sort of unintended problems. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score -1):

Looking at stackoverflow.com/q/4553751/789593 which offers a solution to copy every second one as @N.N. mentioned, a very simple solution would be:

- Remove the first file from the starting folder
- Copy every second one from the starting folder to an intermediate folder
- Copy every seconde one from the intermediate folder into the final folder
- Add the first file manually

It may not be very efficient as it requires an extra copy step bit it should be very easy to do.