# Can I skip N images when creating a gif from png files?

Tags: graphics, conversion, imagemagick

I have several `png` files named `aoa19.5Pressure.XXX.png` where XXXX is a four digit number. The names are such that the numbers are sequential. I want to convert these into a gif. When I run

`convert aoa19.5Pressure.* aoa19.5Pressure.gif`,

my machine takes a very long time to generate the gif. This has many more images than I needed. Is there some way I can convert these `png` files to a `gif` animation, only using every 100th png file to create the `gif`?

Comment: For a more general case see [How to copy every 4th file in a folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59089/22142)

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers are consecutive, just use

```
convert aoa19.5Pressure.*00.png aoa19.5Pressure.gif
```

This will use all images with numbers ending in `00`, in other words every 100th.

Answer (score 1):

A more generalized solution would be to include whatever wildcard you're filtering by in brackets.

Example 1: To take only even frames:

```
convert *[02468].png output.gif
```

Another way to do the same thing would be to delete all odd frames before converting (helpful if you don't want them cluttering your storage):

```
rm *[13579].png
```

and following up with:

```
convert *.png output.gif
```

Example 2: Of course, you can modify the original example if you want to sample more infrequently. You could use the below to filter by every multiple of 5:

```
convert *[05].png output.gif
```