# How to copy every N file when serialization is not consistent

Tags: bash, scripting, filenames, file-copy, move

I have a directory containing 101695 files ranging from img001.jpg to img101693.jpg and I want to move every 100th image to another directory. I have found some similar posts such as [How to copy every 4th file in a folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59089/how-to-copy-every-4th-file-in-a-folder) but those assume that the number of digits in the serial is the same in all files so my range would need to start with img000001.jpg Is there a way to do this or do I need to modify my file names so that they all have the same number of characters in the serial?

Comment: It seems to me that Stéphane's POSIX answer [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59090/117549) handles files of any name, as would [jfg956's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59110/117549) (and others).

Comment: Agreed, @JeffSchaller, although it might be necessary to alter the wildcard to be `img*.jpg` as the accepted answer in that thread uses a five-character wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you ultimately want to spread those files in batches of 100 into several `dir0000` ... `dir1016` directories, in `zsh`:

```
files=( img*.jpg(N.n) )
typeset -Z4 n=0
while (( $#files )); do
  mkdir -p dir$n && cp -- $files[1,100] dir$n/
  (( n++ ))
  files[1,100]=()
done
```

The `n` glob qualifier sorts the files numerically. `typeset -Z4` zero pads `$n` expansions to a length of 4.

With `zsh`'s `zmv`, you could also copy `file<n>.jpg` to `dir<n/100>` and fix the number of digits at the same time with:

```
zmodload zsh/files
mkcp() { mkdir -p -- $2:h && cp -- "$@"; }
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -Pmkcp -n 'img(<->).jpg' \
              'dir${(l[4][0])$(( $1 / 100 ))}/img${(l[6][0])1}.jpg'
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy).

Answer (score 0):

I have a test directory with these dummy files:

```
$ ls img*
img0003.jpg  img001.jpg  img013.jpg  img02.jpg  img10.jpg  img12.jpg
```

Let's use [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr) to move them, or at least simulate moving them, in groups of 2 to a sequence of directories: `dir001`, `dir002`, ...:

```
$ txr move.tl
move img001.jpg -> dir001
move img02.jpg -> dir001
move img0003.jpg -> dir002
move img10.jpg -> dir002
move img12.jpg -> dir003
move img013.jpg -> dir003
```

Code in `move.tl`:

```
(defun normalize (path)
  (collect-each ((tok (tok-str path #/\d+/ t))
                 (i 0))
    (if (oddp i) (toint tok) tok)))

(flow
  (glob "img*.jpg")
  (sort @1 : normalize)
  (tuples 2)
  (do each ((tuple @1)
            (dirnum 1))
    (each ((file tuple))
      (put-line `move @file -> dir@(pic "0##" dirnum)`))))
```

The `normalize` function converts a string like `img001.jpg` into alternating tokens: tokens that don't consists of digits and those that do. The digit tokens are converted to integer type. Examples from the REPL:

```
1> (normalize "img001.jpg")
("img" 1 ".jpg")
2> (normalize "123img001.jpg")
("" 123 "img" 1 ".jpg")
3> (normalize "123img001.jpg42")
("" 123 "img" 1 ".jpg" 42 "")
```

We use this `normalize` function as the basis for sorting the names:

```
4> (glob "img*.jpg")
("img0003.jpg" "img001.jpg" "img013.jpg" "img02.jpg" "img10.jpg"
 "img12.jpg")
5> (sort *4)
("img0003.jpg" "img001.jpg" "img013.jpg" "img02.jpg" "img10.jpg"
 "img12.jpg")
```

Useless order! Let's bring in `normalize`:

```
6> [sort *4 : normalize]
("img001.jpg" "img02.jpg" "img0003.jpg" "img10.jpg" "img12.jpg"
 "img013.jpg")
```

From there it's just a matter of grouping into the group sizes we want and moving to a directory. In the program above this is only simulated with print statements. In the following modified program, the directories are actually created and the files moved:

```
(defun normalize (path)
  (collect-each ((tok (tok-str path #/\d+/ t))
                 (i 0))
    (if (oddp i) (toint tok) tok)))

(flow
  (glob "img*.jpg")
  (sort @1 : normalize)
  (tuples 2)
  (do each ((tuple @1)
            (dirnum 1))
    (each ((file tuple))
      (let ((dirname (pic "dir0##" dirnum)))
        (put-line `move @file -> @dirname`)
        (ensure-dir dirname)
        (rename-path file (path-cat dirname file))))))
```

Run:

```
$ txr move.tl
move img001.jpg -> dir001
move img02.jpg -> dir001
move img0003.jpg -> dir002
move img10.jpg -> dir002
move img12.jpg -> dir003
move img013.jpg -> dir003

$ ls *.jpg
ls: cannot access '*.jpg': No such file or directory

$ ls dir*
dir001:
img001.jpg  img02.jpg

dir002:
img0003.jpg  img10.jpg

dir003:
img013.jpg  img12.jpg
```